# Difference between windows symbolic links and directories

Tags: windows, go, symlink

I run into a problem with Go when trying to tell difference between windows symbolic links and directories.
I've googled and all I could find was this:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3498#issuecomment-142810957

Which is unfortunately closed and not being worked on.

So my question is, is there any workaround? I tried to listdir the path with the symlinks but it is returning the same that it would return on an empty directory.

With python I was able to do something like this:

```
def test(dir):
    try:
        os.chdir(dir)
    except Exception as e:
        if "[Error 2]" in str(e):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Is there any bash command I could use to call from go to detect it?

I'm running out of ideas :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only test I see (and I just tested it with go 1.5.1 on Windows) is in [`os/os_test.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c2025c4131a62bc034c663d2e8c22e37b09fce04/src/os/os_test.go#L600-L602):

```
fromstat, err = Lstat(from)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatalf("lstat %q failed: %v", from, err)
}
if fromstat.Mode()&ModeSymlink == 0 {
    t.Fatalf("symlink %q, %q did not create symlink", to, from)
}
```

It uses [`os/#Lstat`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat):

> `Lstat` returns a [`FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) describing the named file.
>   If the file is a symbolic link, the returned `FileInfo` describes the symbolic link. `Lstat` makes no attempt to follow the link.
>   If there is an error, it will be of type [`*PathError`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#PathError).

You can also get [`os.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Stat) of the same folder, and then call [`os.Samefile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#SameFile) (as [in this test](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c2025c4131a62bc034c663d2e8c22e37b09fce04/src/os/os_test.go#L545-L555)):

```
if !SameFile(tostat, fromstat) {
    t.Errorf("symlink %q, %q did not create symlink", to, from)
}
```